# Lost connection to USB device through USB hub

Tags: raspbian, usb, ethernet

After some physical interference, like moving a bit the USB cable connecting the USB Ethernet card to USB hub, it looses connection -- it's no longer visible in the system, despite the green diode is on and orange one flashes as if it is connected. Rebooting doesn't help. The only solution I found working is to physically unplug the USB Ethernet card from the hub and plug it again causing Raspberry to hard reset.

This is Raspberry PI Zero with Raspbian OS.

Has anyone had such a problem and managed to solve it?

Here are the listings from lsusb:

With Ethernet card working:

```
lsusb
Bus 001 Device 005: ID 046d:c52b Logitech, Inc. Unifying Receiver
Bus 001 Device 004: ID 058f:6387 Alcor Micro Corp. Flash Drive
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 0bda:8152 Realtek Semiconductor Corp. RTL8152 Fast Ethernet Adapter
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 214b:7250  
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

```
lsusb -t
/:  Bus 01.Port 1: Dev 1, Class=root_hub, Driver=dwc_otg/1p, 480M
    |__ Port 1: Dev 2, If 0, Class=Hub, Driver=hub/4p, 480M
        |__ Port 2: Dev 3, If 0, Class=Vendor Specific Class, Driver=r8152, 480M
        |__ Port 3: Dev 4, If 0, Class=Mass Storage, Driver=usb-storage, 480M
        |__ Port 4: Dev 5, If 1, Class=Human Interface Device, Driver=usbhid, 12M
        |__ Port 4: Dev 5, If 2, Class=Human Interface Device, Driver=usbhid, 12M
        |__ Port 4: Dev 5, If 0, Class=Human Interface Device, Driver=usbhid, 12M
```

After the issue occurs:

```
lsusb
Bus 001 Device 008: ID 046d:c52b Logitech, Inc. Unifying Receiver
Bus 001 Device 007: ID 058f:6387 Alcor Micro Corp. Flash Drive
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 214b:7250  
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

```
lsusb -t
/:  Bus 01.Port 1: Dev 1, Class=root_hub, Driver=dwc_otg/1p, 480M
    |__ Port 1: Dev 2, If 0, Class=Hub, Driver=hub/4p, 480M
        |__ Port 3: Dev 7, If 0, Class=Mass Storage, Driver=usb-storage, 480M
        |__ Port 4: Dev 8, If 1, Class=Human Interface Device, Driver=usbhid, 12M
        |__ Port 4: Dev 8, If 2, Class=Human Interface Device, Driver=usbhid, 12M
        |__ Port 4: Dev 8, If 0, Class=Human Interface Device, Driver=usbhid, 12M
```

Comment: yes, solved by replacing USB cable

Comment: @jsotola but was it like a poor quality of the cable itself or the Ethernet card or USB hub controllers?